# Next.js using next-redux-toolkit - How to initially call an action before loading a certain page?

Tags: next.js, next-redux-wrapper

My folder structure looks like this:

```
/ pages
    / [project_id]
        / index.jsx    <- make this (or another external component) call an action before other pages will load
        / assets.jsx
        / information.jsx
        / ...
```

Before I'm accessing the rest of the files, i need a prefetched data saved in a redux state, which needs to be done before any page accessing it loads.
The problem being, is that it requires me to add a `useEffect` hook inside each and every file to load the information i need.

Is there a way to "wrap" these pages with a single action call?

Comment: Hi 

Did you need this prefetch data done on server side ? or on client side

Comment: I'm using redux and i wanted to make an asynchronous action call in client side so yeah

Answer (score 0):

You can make a wrapper component for the data fetching, and later wrap every page in that Layout component where you need to access the data.

First create the wrapper component

```js
// components/Layout.jsx

const Layout = ({ children }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch the data here and store it in redux state
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Then you can use this Layout component in your pages like this

```js
// pages/[project_id]/index.jsx

import Layout from "../../components/Layout.jsx"

const Index = () => {
  // you can access data stored in redux store here
  const { data } = useSelector(state => state.data)

  return (
    <Layout>
     // your page's code goes here
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Comment: This will be useful only in _app.js where it acts like a middleware and allowes **any** page to be rendered as child in this component. I'm talking about the same behavior on another page tree above _app.js, is it possible in next.js?

Comment: Sorry, I might have misunderstood your question, but as far as I know in next.js the _app.jsx renders first and all the pages are rendered as it's child component.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `useEffect` in `_app.js.` It will run only once as `_app.js` is not unmounted upon client side page navigation. And `_app.js` will run whenever you access any page.

If you need to prefetch the data server side, then it becomes a bit more complex and is hardly achieved without `getInitialProps` which `Next.js` wants to deprecate.